# How do I detect the exact alpha value from a single pixel of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics, colors, bufferedimage, alpha

Here is a little block of code I have inside the proper loop to get pixel color data from every pixel in a .PNG BufferedImage..

```
Color pColor = new Color(pixelData[tilePixel], true);

int alpha = pColor.getAlpha();
int red = pColor.getRed();
int green = pColor.getGreen();
int blue = pColor.getBlue();

System.out.println(alpha);

int Pixel = alpha<<24 | red<<16 | green<<8 | blue;
```

the console prints 0's for every pixel regardless of the transparency of the pixel in photoshop. If I just use the drawImage() method from java.awt.Graphics to display the image the transparency shows up fine so I KNOW the alpha data is in there somewhere. I just cant figure out how to get at it. (I thought the boolean true in Color() stood for hasAlpha..? Am I wrong there?)

ALSO!! if I manually edit the alpha like so..

```
Color pColor = new Color(pixelData[tilePixel], true);

int alpha = 150;
int red = pColor.getRed();
int green = pColor.getGreen();
int blue = pColor.getBlue();

int Pixel = alpha<<24 | red<<16 | green<<8 | blue;
```

my render method can print the whole image semitransparent exactly how I would want it to IF it were getting the right alpha pixel data from the image.. So obviously the issue here is that if alpha gets recognized as 0 only my render method never displays anything.. or it displays a 100% transparent image. Still not very helpful!

I've also tried just bypassing the color class like so..

```
int px = pixelData[tilePixel];
int alpha = (px >> 24) & 0xFF;
int red = (px >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (px >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = px & 0xFF;
```

And I'm getting the exact same results. Alpha prints as 0's, hard coding alpha at some value between 0-255 still gives me an appropriately transparent image on screen, red/green/blue are still recognized as expected..

Any insight? I've scoured the internet for this issue and I've found alot of problems with transparency but nothing that QUITE matches my predicament. If I'm not posting enough info here let me know and I can post more code. (This is my first time posting to StackOverflow so I'm unsure of exactly how detailed I need to make my post) Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably won't fix it but I'll take a shot at it, what type are you using as image ? PNG, JPEG ect, maybe the alpha stores itself in various ways depending on the image type, you mention a .ps btw I think, photoshop works with multiple layers so try flattening the pic.

Comment: Tested using a simple gradient filled png and works fine for me. It's possible I'm also missing something, but wouldn't `Color#getRGB` do the same packing as you are doing?

Comment: Do you tried using an image processing library? working over images in Java is painful and time consuming. Are you doing this for an assignment or just to learn more about how to transform images?

Comment: how are you getting `pixelData[]`? Also how did you create the buffered image?

Comment: To user3142- I'm using PNG. I mentioned that. first sentence. To Mad- I'm really not sure. but are you able to print alpha data to console and it give you the proper value? If So I would like to see your code.. To Neo- I'm unsure about that library. I'm only doing this for personal education about how java processes color data and images. To Vandale- I'm new to this Website. how do I post more code? I'll try to get that code up there ASAP.. if I can figure it out..

Comment: To Vandale- Oh shit.. I'm dumb. As soon as I started looking for the code that creates pixelData[] I noticed I commented out where alpha was getting read in from the image!! I must have done that a long time ago before I was using images with transparency for some unknown reason.... aaaghh.. So dumb... but I think i can get it working now.. Is there a way I can mark this as solved and possibly provide my solution or something?